# ¿Como arreglo el problema del comando pip3 y el sdist para python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

recurro a ustedes para aportar una idea y tambien resolver algunas inquietudes.

Dias pasados tuve un problema al crear un paquete distribuible con python 3.7, el script de configuracion ya no se hace con el modulo setuptools, si no con distuils.core sin embargo al ejecutarlo aparece un erro de 'zlib', instalado este puedo ejecutar el 'setup.py' pero con la version 2.7[image: Algunas comandos ejecutados]

Alguna sugerencia o aporte seria de mucha ayuda, al parecer pasa lo mismo cuando quiero instalar un paquete exclusivamente en python 3.7, en el directorio de python 3 esta instalado pip, pero ejecuto 'pip3 --' y me sale error. Encontre esta informacion en un foro pero no se si sea viable ejecutar estos comandos muchas gracias
[image: Error al ejecutar python3 setup.py sdist][image: Solucion que encontre]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si no es mucho trabajo te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta sustituyendo las imagenes por el codigo/error en fortmato **texto** ya que es mas facil de leer , trabajar con el o compartirlo. Puedes usar el siguiente enlace [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses el modulo `PyInstaller`.

```
pip3 install pyinstaller --user
```

o tambien

```
sudo pip3 install pyinstaller
```

El funcionamiento es bien sencillo. Compila un ejecutable con tu script en una carpeta llamada *dist* en el mismo lugar donde esté tu `.py` con la orden

```
pyinstaller script_de_python.py
```

Si usas la opcion *-F* te creará un único archivo con todo lo necesario

```
pyinstaller -F script_de_python.py
```

NOTA: Solo te compila para la versión de `python` que estés ejecutando, es decir, si estas usando `python3` para Linux 32 bits será compatible con Linux 32 bits; si es Windows 64bits pero has instalado Python de 32 bits será de Windows para 32 bits (que también vale para Windows de 64, pero no al revés)

Comment: El problema radica en que el comando con pip3 no funciona, no lo reconoce aunque ya este instalado en python3, en el directorio de python 3.7 no esta instalado, parece que no estuviera relacionado con python3-pip

Comment: Y si ejecutas `pip —version`?